# Running Rails apps with thin as a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, thin

I am trying to run thin as a service on my web server.  After running "sudo thin install", thin created the following file in /etc/init.d/thin

```
#!/bin/sh
DAEMON=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
        $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  stop)
        $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  restart)
        $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

When the thin service is started, the following is ran

```
thin start --all /etc/thin
```

This will scan all of yaml config files defining how to run thin for each app defined.  This does not work.

I see in my logs:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already activated eventmachine 0.12.6, but your Gemfile requires eventmachine 0.12.11. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
  from /srv/app/current/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /srv/app/current/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /srv/app/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /srv/app/current/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
  from /srv/app/current/config.ru:1:in `new'
  from /srv/app/current/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:45:in `for'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:67:in `start'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

When capistrano deploys, I am caching my bundle in in the $APP_PATH/shared/bundle directory; so, this explains why thin complains about gems not being installed as the thin service does not look in the $APP_PATH/shared/bundle

This does work:

```
cd $APP_PATH/current; bundle exec thin start -d -C /etc/thin/app_x.yml
```

but that is not the way the thin service file in /etc/init.d/thin works.  I guess I could write my own.  I just don't want to solve a problem that has already been solved.

Comment: note that the error is not about a gem that is not installed. The problem is about activemachine being activated two times for different versions, and the suggested fix is to run the bundle exec as you are doing.

Comment: VP, yes. It would seem that thin start --all is not aware of each application's existing bundle cache.

Comment: I have a something that works that I am not proud of. https://gist.github.com/712690

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, but I don't feel like it is the best solution as it does not take advantage of thin's "--all" option where it reads the config files from a directory.  Instead I modified the file that starts/stops/restarts the thin service so for each app I give it a specific command for starting/stopping/restarting.  I'm certain this command could be improved, but for now it works for my needs.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is a pretty bad, but effective workaround for starting thin as a service per application.

DAEMON=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin
# DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/bundler thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
  cd /srv/hub/current && bundle exec thin start -d -C /etc/thin/hub.yml
  ;;
  stop)
  cd /srv/hub/current && bundle exec thin stop -d -C /etc/thin/hub.yml
  ;;
  restart)
  cd /srv/hub/current && bundle exec thin restart -d -C /etc/thin/hub.yml
  ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
  exit 3
  ;;
esac
```