# How to start thin for only one application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

In /etc/thin/ I've got several yml files. When I run `service thin stop -C /etc/thin/app.yml` thin stops all applications, instead of only the one I specified.

How do I get thin to stop/start only the specified application?

UPDATE: Hmm, in `/etc/init.d/thin` there's this: `$DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH`. That explains a lot. Are there smarter init.d scripts? This is my script:

https://gist.github.com/1003131

See also:

[Running Rails apps with thin as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261506/136)

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible workaround. does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to edit /etc/init.d/thin adding a new action or modifying the "restart" action.

as you can see, **--all $CONFIG_PATH** sends the command to all thin instances.

paste the init script somewhere, we can find a decent solution ;)

UPDATE:

try to add the following lines, **below** this:

```
restart)
  $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
  ;;
restart-single)
  $DAEMON restart -C $2
  ;;
stop-single)
  $DAEMON stop -C $2
  ;;
```

I didn't tried it, but it should work well. this is a *really simple* solution (no error checking), we've added 2 new actions that must be called as:

```
service thin restart-single /etc/thin/your_app.yml
or
service thin stop-single /etc/thin/your_app.yml
```

let me know if it works ;)

cheers,
A.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the init script, all comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I propose another solution (which i think is more thin-convenient):

1. set the content of your `/etc/init.d/thin` file to use my fixes:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          thin
   # Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
   # Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
   # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
   # Short-Description: thin initscript
   # Description:       thin
   ### END INIT INFO

   # Original author: Forrest Robertson

   # Do NOT "set -e"

   DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/thin
   SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
   CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

   # Exit if the package is not installed
   [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

   if [ "X$2" = X ] || [ "X$3" = X ]; then
       INSTANCES="--all $CONFIG_PATH"
   else
       INSTANCES="-C $3"
   fi

   case "$1" in
     start)
     $DAEMON start $INSTANCES 
     ;;
     stop)
     $DAEMON stop $INSTANCES
     ;;
     restart)
     $DAEMON restart $INSTANCES
     ;;
     *)
     echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart} (-C config_file.yml)" >&2
     exit 3
     ;;
   esac

   :
   ```
2. Use `thin restart -C /etc/thin/my_website.yml`. It is possible to use such syntax with `start`, `restart` and `stop` commands. Yet, `thin restart` (or `start` or `stop`, of course) would inflict all the instances registered.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, I added a patch to the script from the gem itself for the init script for the next build to allow a single restart on future installations

restart-file)
   $DAEMON restart -C $2
;;

but the gem owner refused the merge and said you can use thin start - C /path/ which is weird, because I've tried it a lot and the script itself says --all and no single config is allowed,
I've also tried doing what he said and obviously it restarted all since the script uses all,  can anyone shed more light to this https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/pull/176